# How to read a pre-loaded sqlite database in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite.swift

I am trying to load a pre-loaded sqlite database with .db3 extension but getting error "unexpectedly found nil"

I embedded the file in targetapp >> BuildPhases >> Copy bundle resources.

```
let dat = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "resource", ofType: "db3")
let ddata = try! Connection(dat!, readonly: true)

do{
    for row in try ddata.prepare("SELECT id FROM Categories") {
        print("id\(row[0])")
}
}catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I want to load data into my collectionView

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
let dat = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "resource", ofType: "db3")!
let ddata = try! Connection(dat, readonly: true)
```